# Nginx proxy_pass to socket not working properly ( file not found)

Tags: nginx

I'm not sure what could be wrong here, but i'm trying to forward the traffic for my internal webapp which is using socket, instead tcp port.

Basically, my configuration on nginx, and the file /tmp/webapp.socket exists and with the proper permissions set:

```
upstream webapp{
  server unix:/tmp/webapp.socket;
}

location / {
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_pass http://webapp;
}
```

On the error log:

```
 [crit] 24493#0: *14 connect() to unix:/tmp/webapp.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:

Somehow nginx could not find the file on /tmp, so i had to change the directory to /var/run/